# Ovals are being automatically simplified when drawn using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: polygon, arcgis-pro, simplify, template

Sometimes when I am drawing ellipses in a polygon shapefile, they save correctly and then simplify themselves into angular shapes. I don't understand why this is happening or only happens sometimes, but it's been a consistent--if intermittent--issue in versions 2.6, 2.8 and 2.9.

The two diamond shapes in the below image were drawn using the create > draw ellipse template. They looked fine but after saving, zooming out and back in, they became angular. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

[image: example of angular shapes created using the create ellipse template]

Edited:

Coordinate system is: NAD 83 State Plane North Carolina (US Feet).

As for sizes, the smaller one is about 2.5 x 1ft and the larger is about 5 x 1 ft at their widest. But I have larger ovals turning into many-sided.

The XY Resolution is 0.000000027498... US Survey Feet.
The XY Tolerance is 0.003280333 US Survey Feet.

Correction:
I mistakenly assumed this was a feature class from a geodatabase but instead is a shapefile created in Arc Desktop 10.8.1. Would that make a difference in how ArcGIS Pro is reading this file?

Comment: What coordinate system are you working in? How large are your ovals?

Comment: NAD 83 State Plane North Carolina (US Feet). The smaller one is about 2.5 x 1ft and the larger is about 5 x 1 ft at their widest.

Comment: I have another one at about 10ft x 12ft that has done something similar, but it's become a ~16-sided polygon instead of something as dramatic as these smaller examples.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: I suspect this may have something to do with the resolution on your feature class. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/environment-settings/xy-resolution.htm

Comment: Posted the resolution and tolerance above. As far as I know, this is what it defaulted to. Are they supposed to be equivalent to each other?